# SQL command for distinct values in one column and multiple same values in another

Tags: mysql, sql

My table have the following kind of entries:

```
Serial Number | Cycle Number

55                33

56                27

55                34

55                33

57                5

57                6

56                28

57                6
```

I would like to return distinct Serial Numbers that have multiple Cycle Numbers with the same value

```
Serial Number |  Cycle Number

55                33

55                33

57                6

57                6
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need four rows?  Wouldn't 2 rows with a count provide the same information?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following query that will return the distinct Serial Number which have the multiple Cycle Number with same value.

```
SELECT SerialNumber, CycleNumber
FROM Table
GROUP BY SerialNumber, CycleNumber HAVING COUNT(SerialNumber)>1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really only have two columns, you *could* do:

```
select serial, cycle
from t
where (serial, cycle) in (select serial, cycle
                          from t t2
                          group by serial, cycle
                          having count(*) >= 2
                         );
```

But why wouldn't you just do this?

```
select serial, cycle, count(*)
from t
group by serial, cycle;
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Syntax:

```
SELECT A.* FROM tmpTable A
LEFT JOIN
( 
SELECT SerialNumber,CycleNumber FROM tmpTable  GROUP BY  SerialNumber, CycleNumber having count(SerialNumber)>1
) B ON A.SerialNumber = B.SerialNumber And A.CycleNumber = B.CycleNumber
WHERE B.SerialNumber is not null
```